# Implementing data cache in Android

Tags: java, android, json, caching

My app currently reads in a JSON string from an external datasource and parses it into a `HashMap` of objects. This happens every 10 seconds while the app is open.

I want to implement a cache for that object so that if the user is offline, the last retrieved dataset can still be displayed.

What is the best way to do that? I thought of a few but I'm not sure what's the best way.

1. Write JSON string to internal storage on every data fetch
2. Write JSON string to internal storage when app closes
3. Serialize object and write to internal storage (how?)

Comment: If the payload size is small, option 1 sounds reasonable.

Comment: @myanimal Payload is about 250kb.

Comment: If you were starting fresh I'd recommend using a `SyncAdapter` to fetch the data and persist into a `SQLite` db and use that as your data source via a `ContentProvider`. But that's not the case. I would probably persist the json to disk in a background thread each time I fetched it (as long as it had changed).

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, implement the simplest solution and measure it.

Comment: You can save it on the onSaveInstanceState event, and later reload it on the onCreate. If there is connection, then keep downloading the info, if not, then just use the one you reloaded on the onCreate event. With this I mean option 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Serialize will be the best way to do this. Just create one class whose attributes will be the JSON keys. As for example if your JSON is like

```
   {
     Car:{
     name: "XYZ"
     color: "red"
     }
    }
```

Your class will be:

```
    class Car implements Serializable{
     private String name;
     private String color;
    }
```

Check  [this link](http://www.journaldev.com/2452/java-serialization-example-tutorial-serializable-serialversionuid) to know how to serialize and deserialize object.